# Translate to RA: bi-implication/equivalence

Tags: logic, relational-algebra

(No this isn't one of those translate SQL to RA questions ;-) I have a formula in First-Order Logic that I want to express in RA. That ought to be easy: Codd's 1972 approach in [the Relational Completeness paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.86.9277) is to show each FOL operator can be equivalently expressed in RA.

Given relation `SP`:

- Heading `{S# CHAR, P# CHAR, QTY INT}`
- Key `{S#, P#}`
- Characteristic predicate SP(*s, p, q*) = 'Supplier *s* supplies Part *p* in quantity *q*.'

Express: 'Supplier 'S1' and Supplier 'S2' supply exactly the same set of Parts (disregarding quantities).'

Formula:

```
∀p. (∃q1. SP('S1', p, q1) ) ⇔ (∃q2. SP('S2', p, q2) )
```

Note in case of `S1` supplying no parts at all, this formula is true just in case `S2` also supplies no parts.

This is a Yes/No question (the formula has no free variables); so <s>I'd expect</s> the RA expression must result in a relation with no attributes, returning an empty relation if the two Suppliers do not supply the same set of Parts (formula evaluates to False); otherwise the non-empty relation with no attributes (formula evaluates to True).

To explain a bit further: usually queries return a list of something -- such as the list of Parts supplied by `S1`, disregarding quantities: `SP WHERE (S# = 'S1') {P#}` (or in Greek `π{P#}(σS# = 'S1'(SP))`). For a Yes/No question, we're interested only in whether the query returns something vs nothing, e.g. does Supplier `S1` supply Part `P456`?: `SP WHERE (S# = 'S1' AND P# ='P456') {}` (`π{}(σS# = 'S1'(σP# = 'P456'(SP)))`).

You'll notice I'm using a variant of RA:  **Tutorial D** from [Date & Darwen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(data_language_specification)#Tutorial_D). This is easier to read and typeset than Codd's original RA (I've also included the Greek characters and subscripts form). I'll limit myself to **Tutorial D** operators that correspond to Codd's RA.

I can do the inverse of the query I want: 'Are there any Parts Supplied by `S1` but not by `S2`, or vice versa?'

Firstly a couple of shorthands for common subexpressions

```
WITH S1P := SP WHERE (S# = 'S1'){P#},
     S2P := SP WHERE (S# = 'S2'){P#} :

( S1P MINUS S2P )
UNION
( S2P MINUS S1P );
```

For those who prefer Greek:

`S1P := π{P#}(σS# = 'S1'(SP))

 S2P := π{P#}(σS# = 'S2'(SP))

 (S1P \ S2P) ∪ (S2P \ S1P)`

This'll return an empty result just in case the two Suppliers supply exactly the same set of Parts. So all that remains to do is project that result on to no attributes, and flip empty result to non-empty and vice versa. But Codd's RA doesn't have a way to express that flip, AFAICT.

Applying Codd's 1972 method to the formula, the outermost operation is a forall quantifier, so convert that to a negation of an existential:

```
¬∃p. ¬( (∃q1. SP('S1', p, q1) ) ⇔ (∃q2. SP('S2', p, q2) ) )
```

But now the outermost operation is negation. Codd's method only allows negation to appear nested inside conjunction.

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question? ("Any ideas" about what?) PS A RA query expression returns the tuples that satisfy a predicate. It doesn't return a truth value. You have to tell us what you want returned for when we tell you something is true & when it is false. It's not a matter of what you expect. *We* can expect you to want to get back dee/dum for true/false. PS Easier for whom?

Comment: Yes I carefully didn't ask to return a truth value from RA. I carefully said the formula has no free vars. So <s>I expect</s>the query must return the tuple(s) that satisfy the predicate (sentence). In this case either `Dee` or `Dum` -- although I was trying to avoid that very specific D&D terminology. Return `Dee` in case the two Suppliers supply exactly the same set of Parts. What other result would you expect, given Codd 1972's method? I'll emend the q.

Comment: Re Greek: easier for StackOverflow and its moderators, chiefly. Note that unlike StackExchange, SO does not support MathJax. I could typeset elsewhere and paste an image. But then a busybody will complain about images. I could write HTML tags direct, but then SO will either not format as `code`; or will complain that it seems to be code but not using SO protocols. I've edited to work round those restrictions: to my eye it's ugly, and the subscripts are too small to be readable.

Comment: Start with a non-empty relation. Project it on some subset of attributes; in particular the empty subset. What have you got left? D&D call the result `TABLEDEE` or `Dee` for short. It's a perfectly cromulent relation value. And Codd hinted as much in one of his earlier papers, but didn't follow through the idea into his Algebra.

Comment: Again, what is your question? Stuck at what? You still don't say what you're trying to do; you just make a lot of other statements. I suspect your question has to do with Codd's algebra. You have "Express:" followed by a formula but so what? I suspect that you are trying to say something like "I want to express the following formula as a relational expression:" but you don't say it--or what such an "express" would mean. You don't say why you are writing relational expressions. Please read your post to see what it is actually saying & edit to say what you mean.

Comment: Codd 1972 is very confused, as you've pointed out yourself at length. I'd say Codd didn't understand that he needed `Dee`& `Dum`, because there was much he didn't understand. Your `p AND X=0` is presumably a formula in FOL(?) What does `X=0` correspond to in RA? How do we introduce an attribute `X` if it doesn't come from a relation in the database? Note Codd's RA does not include any way to express relation literals or values for attributes, except inside a comparison subscripted to sigma.

Comment: PS Codd didn't need dee & dum. Any time you want to know the tuples that satisfy a proposition p you can ask for the tuples that satisfy X=0 AND p and infer the set of tuples you want.

Comment: The relation of tuples satisfying X = 0 AND p is the niladic relation of tuples satisfying p JOIN the relation with one tuple < X 0 >. When you would get dee this returns one tuple with X attribute 0 and when you would get dum this returns no tuples. If you would address my request for you to say what "express" means and if you want to "express" under Codd's algebra you would see you would have had to answer your own question just by forcing yourself to be clear.

Comment: If you want RA for tuples satisfying a formula, say so. But then it is immediately obvious that there is no propositional query without niladic relations. Moreover, "I can do the inverse of the query"--no, you can't. Moreover, Codd maps (not operators but expressions of) not FOPL but Alpha to RA. To ask re limitations of specific expressions, operators & relations, please make that clearer & put them in your question. And much question exposition seems unnecessary. PS The paper RA & language just can't express all safe FOPL queries--no constant or function terms or niladic or empty relations!

Answer (score -1):

There is no RA expression that answers the question, if we limit to RA operators and semantics per Codd's 1972 specification.

Even if we add the operators commonly included in RA these days, we can't answer the question as posed. For example, the operators covered in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) such as Rename aka `ρ`, Extend (for calculated columns), Grouping/Aggregation, Outer Joins.

From the discussion, arguably, the desired result (a degree-zero relation) is not countenanced by Codd. I say "arguably" because Codd never rigorously defines 'relation'. There's Codd 1970 footnote 1 "*`R`* is a subset of the Cartesian product *`S1 x S2 x ... x Sn`*."; but no lower bound given for *`n`*. Clearly it's intended to include the degenerate 'product' for *`n`* is 1, then why not allow zero?

For example SQL does not support degree-zero tables. SQL does support pseudo-extending a would-be degree-zero table with a dummy column:

```
SELECT 'Yes' AS Dummy FROM SP WHERE...
```

Even allowing that, I claim the question as posed can't be answered in SQL. (Consider the case where `SP` is empty: then the two Suppliers do supply the same set of Products, viz. the empty set; but the `FROM SP ...` can only return an empty relation.)

Various non-standard operators or primitives have been suggested (see Comments on q and on other answers). AFAICT there is no authoritative reference that 'blesses' any particular approach. For example, [the Alice Book](http://webdam.inria.fr/Alice/) seems not to consider relations of degree zero.

To briefly survey the possible operators/primitives. (Any one of these is expressively equivalent to any other, in the sense that if we have one we can define the others in terms of it -- except for the last.)

Those returning **true/false**:

- Relational comparison: subset `⊆`, which can be used to define equality of relations `==`. (These require the operands to be 'Union Compatible'.)
- `IS_EMPTY( )` (which appears in **Tutorial D**).

The difficulty with returning true/false is that there are no such primitives in RA. (RA operators are usually described as "closed over relations".) Alternatively these operators could return a degree-zero relation; but then why not go to that direct?

Those returning a **degree-zero relation**:

- A complement operation, valid only applied to a degree-zero relation. (This is the "flip" operation discussed in the q.)
- Make `Dee` a primitive -- that is, the non-empty degree-zero relation. Then `Dum =df Dee MINUS Dee`; and in general complement of *`r`* (which must be degree-zero) =<sub>df</sub> `Dee MINUS r`
- Provide primitive(s) to express a relation literal/constant value, just as most programming languages support expressing numeric or String literals, or more complex data structures. Then `Dum/Dee` are just two amongst the many relation constants.

Comment: The question is not clear, and in particular does not clearly define what "relational algebra" or "query formula" means at any point in it, and neither does this answer, and you are just pulling such a relevant detail out of your hat. It demonstrates nothing except that the question is not clear & uses terms without knowing what they mean.